# Query worked fine on localhost but it's very slow on our server

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We've tested with 1 million records on every table, results were fine, always under 0,08.
So we implemented on our server but it's very slow there, taking up to 36 secs.

We've asked for help before to optimize the query we were running on our test machine, we detailed the basic structure of our one to many relationship:
[Problems to optimize large query and tables structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171611/problems-to-optimize-large-query-and-tables-structure)

That's the final query, the one we're using after getting help on the link above:

```
explain 
SELECT
    st.sid, st.title, st.summary, st.storynotes, st.thumb, st.completed, st.wordcount, st.rid, st.date, st.updated,
    stats.total_reviews, stats.total_recommendations,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(catid AS CHAR)) FROM fanfiction_stories_categories WHERE sid = st.sid) as categories,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(genre_id AS CHAR)) FROM fanfiction_stories_genres WHERE sid = st.sid) as genres,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(warning_id AS CHAR)) FROM fanfiction_stories_warnings WHERE sid = st.sid) as warnings
    FROM
    fanfiction_stories st
    LEFT JOIN fanfiction_stories_stats stats ON st.sid = stats.sid
    JOIN fanfiction_stories_categories cat ON st.sid = cat.sid AND cat.catid = 924
    WHERE validated = 1
    ORDER BY updated DESC
    LIMIT 0, 15
```

That's the explain:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14508898/Printscreen/stackoverflow_explain_print_003.PNG

0 rows affected, 6 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 31,356 sec.

**Updated**
We removed some old indexes of the previous DB structure there was at fanfiction_stories and added new indexes to fanfiction_stories_categories, now is much faster. That's the updated explain:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14508898/Printscreen/stackoverflow_explain_print_004.PNG

Sorry, the program that I use only format the explain table as HTML, CSV, etc, doesn't make an ASCII table to display here.

Can we optimize it even more? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: your testserver and production server are equal setup?

Comment: I've revised my query putting category as primary table and where clause... check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There instead of a JOIN you might be better using an explicit INNER JOIN like:

It might also be all the GROUP_CONCAT's that you are doing, they are quite memory hungry.

```
SELECT
    st.sid, st.title, st.summary, st.storynotes, st.thumb, st.completed, st.wordcount, st.rid, st.date, st.updated,
    stats.total_reviews, stats.total_recommendations,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(catid AS CHAR)) FROM fanfiction_stories_categories WHERE sid = st.sid) as categories,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(genre_id AS CHAR)) FROM fanfiction_stories_genres WHERE sid = st.sid) as genres,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(warning_id AS CHAR)) FROM fanfiction_stories_warnings WHERE sid = st.sid) as warnings
    FROM
    fanfiction_stories st
    LEFT JOIN fanfiction_stories_stats stats ON st.sid = stats.sid
    INNER JOIN fanfiction_stories_categories cat ON st.sid = cat.sid AND cat.catid = 924
    WHERE validated = 1
    ORDER BY updated DESC
    LIMIT 0, 15
```

Comment: Hi, Robbie, thanks for reviewing our case. (I'll never get used to "ENTER" KEY = SEND). We're using GROUP_CONCAT because the stories have several genres, warnings, etc, so to avoid duplicated results we're trying that way. Is there any other way to have a similar effect? I know we can GROU BY st.sid, but that will return only the top genre and warning of the story, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should work although I don't have table structures and sample data to simulate.  By removing each of the (SELECT ... ) as Column and just leaving as left joins, group the entire outer query by the sid should give the same result.  I think its more efficient than each subquery AS Column than normal query/join.  The Group_Concat is grouped based on the "sid" at the end anyway and should retain... The only thing that might be an issue is any NULL values at the end on these concat fields which you can then wrap with IFNULL() test.

I would ensure EACH of these tables has index on the "sid" used for the join.  Additionally, your main stories table to have an index on Validated for its criteria = 1.

Based on your feedback, I would shift the criteria and first table to the top by categories..  Get ONE CATEGORY first, then see what stories are associated with it.  Then, from only those stories, hook up the rest of the genre, warnings, comments, etc.  You obviously have a smaller set of categories, so I would hit THAT as the primary table in the query.  Let me know how this works.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      st.sid, 
      st.title, 
      st.summary, 
      st.storynotes, 
      st.thumb, 
      st.completed, 
      st.wordcount, 
      st.rid, 
      st.date, 
      st.updated,
      stats.total_reviews, 
      stats.total_recommendations,
      GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT cat.catid ) categories,
      GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT genre.genre_id ) genres,
      GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT warn.warning_id ) as warnings
   FROM
      fanfiction_stories_categories cat
         JOIN fanfiction_stories st
            ON cat.sid = st.sid
            AND st.Validated = 1
            LEFT JOIN fanfiction_stories_stats stats 
               ON st.sid = stats.sid
            LEFT JOIN fanfiction_stories_genres genre
               on st.sid = genre.sid
            LEFT JOIN fanfiction_stories_warnings warn
               on st.sid = warn.sid
   WHERE 
      cat.catid = 924
   group by 
      st.sid
   ORDER BY 
      updated DESC
   LIMIT 
      0, 15
```

Comment: Your query works fine, but takes 2,5 seconds to return the results in our production server, every table with index on sid, categories table with index at catid too. My query works faster but I don't think that it is the correct approach to the problem, while yours looks better but takes more time... :T

Comment: @Michael, do you also have an index on the fanfiction_stories by the Validated column to qualify the WHERE clause?  Also, I've added keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN"... Try that and let me know the performance difference.  (actually, try the STRAIGHT_JOIN BEFORE doing Validated index)

Comment: Thank you @DRapp, but that didn't worked. I had index on validated, I dropped to test the STRAIGHT JOIN, took 5.3 sec, that's the explain: http://bit.ly/eJbsFf - Now with index on validated: http://bit.ly/gRdNMM - And that's using the index validated_updated with fields (valided, updated): http://bit.ly/i7EPrY . Using STRAIGHT_JOIN with the index validated or validated_updated I get 4 seconds. Your query looks the right way to do it, but I'm missing something, I can't decrease the time and improve performance =/

Comment: @Michael, What is your purpose of the Category of only 924? For your sample, are you only interested in a specific category of movies and want to see all the stats for THAT category? If so, I would restructure the query differently.

Comment: This query is supposed to be the main query for listing on categories (we have like 1k), and that "category = 924" has been added to get only stories from that category, but could be anything from 1 to 1k, for example. There are aditional filters, to list only from that category with genre Y and warning Y, or from that category with genre X, without genre Y and without warning Y, an so on. I'm pulling out my hair to achieve the best query possible, as this is the main query of the website. Thanks for helping me =)

Comment: @Michael, I've revised answer and shifted query basis.

Comment: @DRapp thank you, with that query the results are retrieved in 2,5 seconds. When there are just a few results (like 200), it's faster, but for 1k+ takes around seconds and half, so I couldn't use it on our production server. I don't think it's possible to optimize it any further. Thank you for your effort, I've learned a lot.